# Why is my AngularFire push( ) not working?

Tags: angularjs, undefined, firebase, angularfire, controllers

I'm trying to learn Angular with Firebase by running through a typical to-do tutorial, but I'm sort of modifying the app as I go. Instead of list of to-dos, I'm actually creating 'Users'.

Firebase is set up correctly, pulling object data down from Firebase works as well and I can see everything populating as expected via ng-repeat.

But I'm trying to 'add a new member' using the .push() method, and I'm receiving an error. Please take a look:

Here's an example of the JSON data that I uploaded to Firebase (just one user)

```
{
  "members": {
    "-JWT5y43YFy1mGirVVS2": {
    "date": 1410328158691,
    "firstname": "Michael",
    "lastname": "Jordan",
    "project": "sample project description",
    "image": "http://telehealth.org/wp-content/images/user-placeholder.jpg",
    "upcoming": "PTO on Thursday",
    "status": {
      "color":  "red",
      "contact": {
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "yahoo": "yahooIM"
        },
      "projects": {
        "projectone": "project one",
        "projecttwo": "project two",
        "projectthree": "project three"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my .html code

```
<h1 id="teamTitle">Team Members</h1>
<div class="addMember">
    <p>add member</p>
    <form class="formmember"
        name="memberform"
        ng-submit="addMember()"
        novalidate>
            <div class="inputwrapper">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder"First Name" ng-required="true">
                <button type="submit" class="btn"
                ng-disabled="memberform.$invalid">Add</button>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid" ng-repeat="member in members">
    <li class="{{member.status.color}}">
        <img src="{{member.image}}">
        <div>
            <h3>{{member.firstname}}</h3>
            <button>View</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's my Controller.js

```
myApp.controller('MembersController', function($scope, $firebase){

var ref = new Firebase('https://scrumcheck.firebaseio.com/members');
var members = $firebase(ref);

$scope.members = members.$asObject();

$scope.addMember = function(){
    members.$push({
        firstname: $scope.firstname,
        date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    });
}

});
```

The console log shows this error:

```
 Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'firstname'
```

I was hoping that by pushing to Members, an object with just the firstname key, it would allow me to do so. Am I only allowed push() an entire object, with all key-values in it?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using save() instead of push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout your $scope.firstname model, that's where the issue is. make sure it's not a null value and properly defined.

Comment: you were right, I didn't even have ng-model in there at all! This is what happens when with us 3am devs...